# The SSL Module doesn't install

Tags: python, ssl, module

I'm trying to install ssl module to python, but doesn't work and i don't have any idea why. Pls someone can help me

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyqst.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip3 install ssl
```

as it seems your command tries to load some python 2 code.